# Nginx timeout error using Docker and nextcloud-fpm

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nextcloud

I have a docker-compose file using nginx, nextcloud-fpm, mariadb, and redis (see below). The mariaDB and Redis connections appear fine, however I can't get any kind of web interface (accessing via nginx port 80) to work. Each attempt to connect times out after a couple of minutes and Nginx gives no logs to troubleshoot.

I'm fairly new to nginx so any help would be greatly appreciated. Note: I do have a reverse proxy setup already and just need nginx to be the web server, so I don't care about TLS and just need it to work on port 80. Additionally, the .env files literally jsut reference passwords.

Attempting to access in the browser at http://10.0.0.234:8008

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

##########################################################################
services:


  nextcloud-nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    hostname: nextcloud-nginx
    container_name: nextcloud-nginx
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud-fpm
#    environment:
    labels:
      - traefik.backend=nextcloud
      - traefik.docker.network=public
      - traefik.enable=false
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:cloud.example.com
    networks:
      - nextcloud-front
#      - public
    ports:
      - 10.0.0.234:8008:80/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
#      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nginx:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw #assigned dir
#      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro #config file
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nextcloud-fpm:/usr/share/nginx/html:rw #from nextcloud
#    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;'] #for debugging only


  nextcloud-fpm: #https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud
    image: nextcloud:production-fpm
    hostname: nextcloud-fpm
    container_name: nextcloud-fpm
    depends_on:
      - nextcloud-mariadb
      - nextcloud-redis
    environment:
      - NEXTCLOUD_ADMIN_USER=admin1 #nextcloud admin uname
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud #database superuser uname
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud #database name
      - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud-mariadb #hostname of database
      - REDIS_HOST=nextcloud-redis #hostname of redis
#      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=n
    env_file: /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nextcloud-nextcloud-fpm.env
    networks:
      - nextcloud-back
      - nextcloud-front
    ports:
      - 10.0.0.234:42008:80/tcp
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nextcloud-fpm:/var/www/html:rw #assigned dir
#      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/users/user:/NFS/user:rw #mount NFS share as Nextcloud files


  nextcloud-mariadb: #https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb
    image: mariadb:latest
    hostname: nextcloud-mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud #user created w/ superuser permission to the database on first startup
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud #database created on first startup
      - bind-address=0.0.0.0 #allows network access
    env_file: /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/nextcloud-mariadb.env
    networks:
      - nextcloud-back
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql:rw #assigned dir
#      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/mariadb/nextcloud-mariadb-conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d:ro #config file


  nextcloud-redis: #https://hub.docker.com/_/redis
    image: redis:latest
    hostname: nextcloud-redis
    container_name: nextcloud-redis
    networks:
      - nextcloud-back
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/redis:/data:rw #assigned dir
#      - /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/BESSy/nc-test/redis/config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf:rw #config file


#########################################################################
networks:

  public: #connect the web server to the reverse proxy
    external:
      name: public

  nextcloud-front: #connect nextcloud to the web server
    name: nextcloud-front
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.42.21.0/24

  nextcloud-back: #connect nextcloud to the database
    name: nextcloud-back
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 10.42.22.0/24
```

### nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #added manually to test
#    proxy_connect_timeout 600;
#    proxy_send_timeout 600;
#    proxy_read_timeout 600;
#    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
#    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream php-handler {
        server localhost:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;

        # Add headers to serve security related headers
        # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into this
        # topic first.
        # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
        # includeSubDomains; preload;";
        #
        # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
        # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
        # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
        # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
        # could take several months.
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
        add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
        add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
        add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

        root /var/www/html;

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        # The following 2 rules are only needed for the user_webfinger app.
        # Uncomment it if you're planning to use this app.
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        #rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json
        # last;

        location = /.well-known/carddav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }
        location = /.well-known/caldav {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
        }

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 10G;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Enable gzip but do not remove ETag headers
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_min_length 256;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private no_last_modified no_etag auth;
        gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/ld+json application/manifest+json application/rss+xml application/vnd.geo+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/bmp image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/cache-manifest text/css text/plain text/vcard text/vnd.rim.location.xloc text/vtt text/x-component text/x-cross-domain-policy;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            # fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff2?|svg|gif)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers (It is intended to
            # have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read into
            # this topic first.
            # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
            #  includeSubDomains; preload;";
            #
            # WARNING: Only add the preload option once you read about
            # the consequences in https://hstspreload.org/. This option
            # will add the domain to a hardcoded list that is shipped
            # in all major browsers and getting removed from this list
            # could take several months.
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;

            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }

}
```